# How do I actually view my lifecycle hooks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, autoscaling

Lifecycle hooks are managed via cli only right now.

All I see in the docs are commands for adding and performing lifecycle hook actions- how do I actually view them?

I add a lifecycle hook to an ASG with put-lifecycle-hook. Ok great, but where/how is that visible? Is this a tag? Can I view it in the console somewhere? Is there a command that reveals this?

If no know one can easily view if a lifecycle hook is attached to an ASG it would be bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Get-ASLifecycleHooks might be what I want: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Auto_Scaling_cmdlets.html